# create or update mongodb with an object [node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im trying to create/update mongodb

Why do I get always an error with this code?

My DB schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  userAddress: {street: {type: String}, city: {type: String}, zip: {type: String}},
  userId: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },

});

var AddressObj = { street:address['addressLine1'], city:address['city'], zip:address['postalCode']  };


User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {userId:  userID}, 
        { $set: { "userAddress" : AddressObj} },
        function(err, doc){
            if(err){
                console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
            }

            console.log(doc);
        });
```

There is no error. Just no item in DB ;(

Comment: What is the error you get? What is the schema type for `name` - Is it `String` or `Schema.Types.Mixed`?

Comment: Can you post your User schema here?

Comment: please post the schema

Comment: I updated my code. I will be very appreciate for any help. It is so strange. I get no error at all. Just nodejs doesnt save my entry :(

Comment: Why do you use find one and update if you want to create one ? Seems normal to me that it doesn't create one because it doesn't find one before hand.

Comment: So what code should I use? When I update with one property like only it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell mongoose to create a new doc if one does not exist. You do this by specifying the upsert option as part of the 3rd parameter. Like so:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {userId:  userID}, 
        { $set: { "userAddress" : AddressObj} },
        {upsert:true, new:true},  //upsert to create a new doc if none exists and new to return the new, updated document instead of the old one. 
        function(err, doc){
            if(err){
                console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
            }

            console.log(doc);
        });
```